# Create trigger in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger inside stored procedure as it will be removed when the table is dropped.

I am getting an error and am not able to execute it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EC5Trigger2
AS
  CREATE TRIGGER trVendorProductsPST
  ON VendorProducts
  FOR INSERT
  AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE  @SKU VARCHAR(64)
    SELECT @SKU = I.SKU FROM inserted AS I

    INSERT INTO ProductStockTransactions (SKU, stockingCode)
    VALUES (@SKU, 'A')
  END

  RETURN 0
```

Comment: why you wanna create a trigger more than once? I assume that since you made it in a procedure

Comment: your trigger is broken anyway and wont work as intended for multirow inserts. you should get rid of the assignment to the scalar variable and just insert straight from `inserted` to the target table

Comment: triggers 
should be saved in a stored procedure as dropping & creating tables WILL REMOVE any triggers. That's why I am doing this. But not able to please help.

Comment: Ok thank you my professor told me to save it in SP that's why I was trying.

Comment: No, you just need to run it once and the trigger is created..... no need for a stored procedure

Comment: Why aren't you solving the basic problem : `I am trying to save trigger in SP as it will be removed when the table is dropped.` the simplest solution is to save the create trigger in file. After you re-create the table, just execute the create trigger script

Comment: `my professor told me to save it in SP`. I wonder who else do that in real life ?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: @marc_s i will have to use while loop or something else right to solve the issue?

Comment: **NO** - neither a cursor, nor a while loop - use a **proper, set-based** approach - that's the most efficient by far

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you create your trigger inside a stored procedure using dynamic SQL, which is the only way to do it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EC5Trigger2
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @TriggerCode NVARCHAR(max);

  SET @TriggerCode = 'CREATE TRIGGER trVendorProductsPST
    ON VendorProducts
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      DECLARE @SKU VARCHAR(64)
      SELECT @SKU = I.SKU from INSERTED as I

      INSERT INTO ProductStockTransactions (SKU, stockingCode)
        VALUES (@SKU, ''A'')
    END';

  EXEC(@TriggerCode);

  RETURN 0;
END;
```